# Serialize any type of list item

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have this Any type of list;

```
val sendMetas = mutableListOf<Any>()
sendMetas.add(CarType(count = "2",type = 2))
```

When sending to the server it should go like this;

```
"Metas": [{
"car_type": {
    "count": "1",
    "type": 3
}}]
```

But instead, it goes like this;

```
"Metas":[{"count":"2","type":2}]
```

How can I surround with serialize name I have couple more objects like CarType. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I handled by turning into JsonObject;

```
 val jsonObject = JsonObject()
 jsonObject.addProperty("count", "1")
 jsonObject.addProperty("type", 3)

 val prepTimeJson = JsonObject()
 prepTimeJson.add("car_type", jsonObject)
 sendMetas.add(prepTimeJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Metas" field in exptected json is array of "Meta" object, so instead of adding "CarType" instances in "sendMetas" array you should create "Meta" (data)class with "car_type" field, so it'll look like that:

```
data class Meta (
  val car_type: CarType
)

data class CarType (
  val count: String,
  val type: Int
)

val sendMetas = mutableListOf<Meta>()
sendMetas.add(Meta(car_type = CarType(count = "2",type = 2)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't surround by Meta object and put CarType and other XType objects in it. The server won't accept it. All list items must be independent like this;
"Metas": [{
  "x_type": {
   "time": "12",
   "type": 3
  }
 }, {
  "car_type": {
   "count": "3",
   "type": 29
  }
 }]

Comment: @dgncn , I think you still can use "Any" type in "sendMetas" list. If it won't work you can  try and change Meta class to have all expected fields, but make them nullable like this: `data class Meta ( val car_type: CarType?, val x_type: XType? )`.